# How to mount FTP drive with read+write and write+seek option

Tags: raspbian, mount, tftp

**Long story**

I'm trying to use my Raspberry as a media server which automatically downloads new TV show episodes. One of the things I did until now is to install and set up Deluge which was fine and stopped working when I changed the downloading path. No torrent could be downloaded and all got stuck in status `Operation not supported /mnt/fantec/deluge/downloading/<TorrentFile>`. It took me a while but then I discovered that the problem wasn't with deluge but with `curlftpfs` which I used to mount the NAS through FTP:

> Be aware that some applications might not be able to “save” files on
>   curlftpfs from 0.9.2 on, because we don’t support open(read+write) or
>   open(write) and seek anymore

(I can't find the original link were this was posted but is all over the internet).

**Short story**

I need to mount an FTP server as a drive as with `curlftpfs` being able to change permissions and open files for read+write and write+seek.

**Tech details**

The raspberry is Raspberry Pi 3 Model B running a RaspbianOS (I think with noobs). The NAS is a Fantec CL-35B1 which is supposed to also have SMB but I can't get either the users nor the permissions manipulation work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very late response but I came across this while searching for an answer myself. I solved this problem by setting deluge to download to a local directory on the Pi first, then use the "move on completed" option in deluge to move the completed file to your mounted curlftpfs directory. It will successfully seed as well.

Hope this helps someone who ends up here from google like I did.

Comment: Thanks @Jonny. I ended up changing how the external disk was connected to the raspberry, but I could give that a try :-)